# Show checkbox checked from database

Tags: laravel

Hope you're all fine.
I have an article, and I want to be able to edit it. Inside the article, I have checkboxs, and what I want is to check the ones I've checked when I first create the article (Im using a pivot table).

I have this code for now.

```
    public function createArticle(Request $request)
    {
       $data = $request->validate([ 
        'titreArticle' => 'bail|required|between:5,40',
        'typeArticle' => 'bail|required',
        'themeCheckbox' => 'required',
        'themeCheckbox.*' => 'required',
        'contenuArticle' => 'bail|required',
       ]);
       $type_articles = Type_article::findOrFail($data['typeArticle']);
       $article = new Article();

       $article->type_article()->associate($type_articles);
       $themes = Theme::whereIn('theme_id', array_keys($data['themeCheckbox']))->get();
       $article->titre = $data['titreArticle'];
       $article->contenu = $data['contenuArticle'];
       $article->save();
       $article->theme()->attach( $themes);

       return view('admin');
   }
```

And inside my view :

```
@foreach ($themes as $theme)  
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="themeCheckbox[{{$theme->theme_id}}]" value="1" > 
      <label class="form-check-label">{{ $theme->nom_theme }}</label>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

I've seen I must use `contains` but don't really know how to use it...

Cordially

Comment: That's not a checkbox in the part of the view you've shared. That's a text area

Comment: i've edited my question, sorry.

Comment: Assuming you have `boolean` for the db data type,Something like `@if($theme->themeCheckbox.$theme->theme_id == '1') checked @else @endif`

Comment: Inside my column `theme`, I have `theme_id` and `name` which content the name of the theme. With your code, only the 1st checkbox is checked, even if I did not check it when I created the article.